# AngularJS - How to copy a link to the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table where one of the cells contains a link to a different page. At the end of the table I am trying to implement a "Copy to Clipboard" button that's function when clicked would copy the link from a cell to the user's clipboard so that they can paste.

I have found that the browsers I want to support have:

```
  document.execCommand('copy')
```

But I cannot find any documentation if this takes in parameters or what exactly gets copied just by referencing document.

Any ideas how I can pass any string to the user's clipboard?

Comment: this can give you some idea http://jsfiddle.net/YP9QP/

Answer (score 0):

document.execCommand('copy') behaves like pressing ctrl+c. So, you need to highlight that string at first, and after that invoke that command.
For that purpose I'm using this library: https://sachinchoolur.github.io/ngclipboard/